# Possible to track a div click with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, onclick

I have a video playing within a div on a site. The video requires a click to play.  I'm wondering if it would be possible to apply some analytic event tracking tO the parent div that tracks anytime there is a click within the div.

I know you can use an onClick event with analytics, but am not quite sure if it could be applied to a div rather than, say, an outbound link like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'vid 1']);">Click Here</a>
```

Has anybody body ever done something like this?  I realize there are some downfalls to this (user repeatedly clicking play/pause) etc.

Thanks.

*Edit - I should probably have mentioned that I am unclear of how I would turn the div into a clickable event.

Say my div is .  What would I need to do to make the whole div into an onClick event?

Comment: Why didn't you just try this and see if it works? In my opinion, it should!

Comment: Because I am unsure of how to make the whole div a clickable event.  I probably wasn't clear in my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly do something like this:

```
<div onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'vid 1'])" 
    style="cursor: pointer;"> Your content here </div>
```

**However**: when you place flash inside, there could be issues with click propagation, depending on your browser. It is better to give this library a try:

[Google Analytics Tracking for Adobe Flash](http://code.google.com/intl/sk/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingIntro.html)  Library.

Comment: Except, if you click on the containing `div` **within** the `flash` area, it won't bubble to the `div`. So, the latter half of this answer is probably the only part that will work.

Comment: The original question was: "What would I need to do to make the whole div into an onClick event". My first part answers that explicit question. However, you're right, this is not practical if there's flash inside. Thus the second part of the answer. While not a direct answer to his question, this solves his problem. But the first part is needed for the sake of thers, there are "google-analytics" and "onclick" tags on this question.

Answer (score 3):

Or if you are using Google's newer analytics.js tracking code:

```
<div  onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'My Wonderful Div');" style="cursor: pointer;"> Your content here </div>
```

To test, provided you have a google analytics account and the analytics.js is embedded in your page, this will show up in your Google Analytics Dashboard under 'Standard Reports' > 'Real-Time' > 'Events'... Event Action: click,  Event Label: My Wonderful Div

or more permanently under

'Behavior' > 'Events'

Comment: Glad I was of some use!